# Different Components under Same URL in Angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, routes

I have a situation where I need to display two different components say `A` and `B` under same URL `C`. Currently, I' am displaying `A` which is a modal using `Location` service's `go` method which updates URL but doesn't activate `Route` to load appropriate components. This solution is working fine. The only problem related to this is that if user interacts with browser's `back` and `forward` buttons then the other component `B` mentioned in `Route` config is displayed which is not what I intended.

I only want to load `B` under same URL when user refreshes page. For example, if user clicks a button, then I' am loading `A` by updating browser's URL via `Location` service giving user the illusion that the URL is properly loaded. Now if at this point, users refreshes the page, I want to display `B` which is a completely different template.

Is there any way, where I can pass dynamic data in components while loading them without displaying dynamic data in URL?

Comment: Having a little trouble picturing the issue here. If I am understanding this correctly you should create a new component that contains components `A` and `B`.  You can then use a variable to switch between the two components by using a `*ngIf` in your html template.

Comment: @DavidLee, thanks for commenting. Yeah, you are right. That could be a possible solution. However, how would I be passing that variable to the component holding `A` and `B`. Can I pass dynamic `data` in `Router#navigate` or `Router#navigateByUrl` methods? Or I would need to do this via some service (which seems overkill for such small thing)?

Comment: Not sure what your components look like.  You could hold a variable in your `Location` service, lets say its a boolean called `showA` that defaults to the value `false`.  This can be set to `true` when you wish to show component `A`.  If the user refreshes, the refresh will set all your variables back to the default values, in this case `false` and in turn will show component `B`.  Using the url to make the switch won't work as a refresh will always have the same query string.